# ES6 change to fixed values in API request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

How do I change the values of my object to use the fixed values as I have done with my console.log?

```
fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(fullAPI).then(res => {
      const apiResponse = res.data
      apiResponse.forEach(employee => console.log('test', employee.value.toFixed(2)))
      apiResponse.forEach(employee => employee.value.toFixed(2))
      console.log('raw data', apiResponse)
      this.setState({
        employeeData: apiResponse,
      })
    })
  }

test 4.41
test 5.00
test 6.16
test 0.79

raw data 
(10) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {name: "Animals", value: 4.41361634}
1: {name: "Environment", value: 5.004498622999998}
```

Comment: `.forEach(employee => employee.value = employee.value.toFixed(2))` ??

Comment: ^^ what he said (although I'm not a fan of single line arrow functions for scenarios like this, the readability is poor).

Comment: @James what would be a more readable way to do it?

Comment: @invrt use brackets, as demonstrated in Nick's answer below. Or if you aren't precious about the original array, use `map` and replace it completely with a single line `map(({ name, value }) => ({ name, value: value.toFixed(2) }))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error with your code is that you are just formatting the `value` number and returning it to `forEach` (that does nothing with this information).

You must modify the original object.

```
fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(fullAPI).then(res => {
      const apiResponse = res.data;
      apiResponse.forEach(employee => {
        employee.value = employee.value.toFixed(2); // Note we are attributing the fixed value to the value itself, modifying the object
      });
      console.log('raw data', apiResponse)
      this.setState({
        employeeData: apiResponse
      })
    })
  }
```

Note that this works because JavaScript always use a reference for objects (like a pointer in C), so even without returning the object, you are changing it properties and it will reflect on the original array.

IMO is more readable for non experienced (and experienced as well) programmers using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead, since it will make clear that you are modifying the object and updating the array:

```
fetchData = () => {
    axios.get(fullAPI).then(res => {
      const apiResponse = res.data;
      apiResponse.map(employee => {
        employee.value = employee.value.toFixed(2)
        return employee;
      });
      console.log('raw data', apiResponse)
      this.setState({
        employeeData: apiResponse
      })
    })
  }
```

Both codes will do the same, probably no performance differences, just different readability.

Comment: For what reason? As much as you _can_ use `map`, why would you when you can use `forEach`? I've suggested the potential use of `map` in the comments but with semantic reasons, I could swap out `map` for `forEach` in this answer and it would work just the same.

Comment: Both works fine. Map will require the return and forEach not. But IMO using forEach uses an obvious but not well know property of javascript (objects are always passed as reference). Map will make clear to read that you are changing that object.

Comment: Really just a code readability concern, but using forEach is not wrong at all.

Comment: @James, I've updated the answer to be more complete on why OP's code is not working, and showing both ways to let he choose.

Comment: I'm not sure I 100% agree with your reasoning (I personally don't believe map is any more readable than `forEach` here, they both serve different purposes). However, the question was more rhetorical to encourage you to improve your answer (which you have now done) 

Comment: also, you explain (and rightly so) that `forEach` makes use of object references so updating the property isn't as readable as using map as you return the object....but you gain nothing here. You could actually remove the `return` line from your `map` call and end up with the same result - `forEach` is _technically_ the correct solution, you can use `map` also but unless you are going to perhaps do what I suggested in my comment (return a new object) you are really just writing more code for the sake of it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `employee.value` to the desired value. Additionally, I recommend not using the implicit return syntax and use braces for readability.

```
apiResponse.forEach(employee => {
  employee.value = employee.value.toFixed(2);
});
```